# IPA has to be regenerated if there is new trusted devices?

Tags: ios, react-native, ipa

I've first generated IPA and distributed to few iPhone devices and later found out that there are few iPhones that doesn't have the signing Certificate from my mac, so I added them via XCode and try to distribute the early generated IPA but none of them successfully installed. It only works after I run thru the whole process again (build -> archieve -> validate -> export)? Am I understand correctly that IPA only meant for trusted devices before the IPA generated?

Comment: Correct. The provisioning profile is contained in the IPA. Adding new devices to the developer portal won't be in the existing ipa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely, whenever you add any new device and created new profile you **must** create new archive so newly added device will be able to instal the ipa.
As Apple restrict the untrusted device to use the apps code signing is must and when you code sign the profile matches the certificate.

As while creating archive the profile is used while exporting. The old ipa created do not include the new Profile hence the new devices too.

So whenever you add even single device new ipa creation is required.